# How to assign leads to a campaign using der Data Import Wizard (for leads)

Tags: csv, campaign-member, data-import

I want to import leads with a CSV-file and assign them to an existing campaign. The CSV contains a field 'campaign' with the name of the campaign.

1. If you import the CSV with the Data Import Wizard from the *Campaign page > Campaign Members > Manage Members > Import File* the leads are **assigned correctly** to the corresponding campaign.
2. If you import the CSV from *Setup > Administer > Data Management > Data Import Wizard* with leads (checkboxes equal to 1.) the leads are **NOT assigned** to the campaign.
   [image]

I like to import leads and assign them to different campaigns in one CSV-file, so way 2. would be the best.

Remark: the Data Import Wizard will not work correctly with Firefox (MIME-type error) - use Chrome instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the approach 2 that you have mentioned, I haven't seen any option of associating leads to a Campaign. I don't think you can use that. The only thing that I can think of is using Data Loader in 2 steps:

1. Import the Lead CSV. Make sure the CSV file also contains the column of Campaign ID.
2. Once imported, get the success file. It will have the LeadID, CampaignId. You can additionally add the column for Status (or this can be present at the start). Use this file to import to CampaignMember object.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for approach 2. with Data Import Wizard (thanks RajeshShah for the hint!)

Using 2. and generate a field CampaignID with the Campaign ID (instead of campaign name) of the desired campaign. The mapping will work automatically and the imported leads are assigned correctly.

Comment: So if the CSV file has a column CampaignId, there is a mapping for the Campaign ID directly in the Lead data Import Wizard?